# How to solve the problem Error in UseMethod?

Tags: r, deep-learning, survival-analysis, concordance-index

I used the code

```
library(survivalmodels)
library(survival)
library(reticulate)

set.seed(10)
data <- simsurvdata(20)
fit <- deepsurv(data=data[1:10, ])
p <- predict(fit, type="risk", newdata=data[11:20, ])
concordance(risk=p, truth=data[11:20, "time"])
```

and ran into this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("concordance") :
  no applicable method for 'concordance' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Can you please add the needed `library`s to use your code, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it! please give me solution !

Comment: You are supposed to run concordance on the model fit, not the vector of predictions. However, I'm not sure if `concordance` even _has_ a method for objects of class 'survivalmodel'. Why did you think this was possible? Are you following a tutorial?

Comment: I have run into some Python issues, so can't help. I have added the Python tag, as apparently appropriate expertise is needed.